# How do I convert 'hhmmssss', as a number, to date or time format?

Tags: oracle

Very new to Oracle so totally at a loss of how to do this.
I have times stored as numbers like below (hhmmssss):

| PROCESS_TIME |
| --- |
| 10150450 |
| 2034039 |

I want to display these as below:

| PROCESS_TIME |
| --- |
| 10:15:0450 |
| 2:03:4039 |

When AM time there is no leading 0. What is the best way to do that?

Would a simple TO_CHAR work where the number length is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with data  (process_time) as (
    select '10150450' from dual union all
    select '2034039' from dual
)
select regexp_replace(process_time, '(^\d{1,2})(\d{2})(\d{4}$)', '\1:\2:\3' )
from data 
;


10:15:0450
2:03:4039
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it to a timestamp using `TO_TIMESTAMP` and then use `TO_CHAR` to format it:

```sql
SELECT process_time,
       TO_CHAR(
          TO_TIMESTAMP( LPAD(process_time, 8, '0'), 'HH24MISSFF2' ),
          'HH24:MI:SS.FF2'
       ) AS time
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (PROCESS_TIME) AS
SELECT 10150450 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2034039  FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| PROCESS_TIME | TIME |
| --- | --- |
| 10150450 | 10:15:04.50 |
| 2034039 | 02:03:40.39 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iYOYpRbj)